# Tablet/app to crop a pdf given settings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, mobile, tablet

I have a bunch of settings, that is, Javascript files referencing 'BBox' and 'Crop' document boxes in PDF files, which are used with Adobe Acrobat SDK to crop files.

They're collected for other scientists to implement on their own computers at [GitHub](https://github.com/lmmx/CropScience).

I've been asked if it's possible to get a tablet/mobile version, and in theory it should be since I have settings, but I can't find any mention of a mobile SDK other than the Acrobat Reader, which to my knowledge doesn't do crops.

Does anyone know of any way I could do this? I've read Android and PDFs aren't the easiest to work with, so not expecting much but thought it was worth asking.

Sample cropping Javascript from the files I have:

```
var d = ['Art','Bleed','Trim','Crop'];
var o;
function n() { return this.numPages; }
function a() { return this; }

for (var p=0; p < n(); p++) {
   o = a().getPageBox('BBox', p);
   o[1] -= 50;
   o[2] -= 10;

   for (b = 0; b < 4; b++) {
      a().setPageBoxes(d[b], p, p, o)
    }
};
```

Comment: FYI: that Javascript is going to get you nowhere. It's specifically for Adobe Acrobat itself, running inside Acrobat. It will not "do" anything on any other platform, inside any other program.

Comment: you leave my Javascript alone! I guess you're right, in an ideal world there'd be an API out there that also takes Javascript instructions... Essentially all the Javascript contains are references to the borders though (numbers are in units of pt), so I don't really think it's all that “specifically for Acrobat”. If anyone suggests another way to perform operations on PDF programmatically I'm all ears. I just provided it so readers were clear what I'm working with. That is, I'm aware any mobile API won't take equivalent commands, and may not even be made by Adobe.

Comment: I'd assume the page size is one of the most fundamental properties of a PDF, and thus possibly even a mobile app could access it. But as I say, I'm no expert and I'm only asking since I have all these settings "trapped" in [the Adobe SDK](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) as you rightly say, and am wondering what else I might be able to do with them to make 'em more useful.